# SharePoint Online Guest Access and Share Capability

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, share, azure-ad

Is there a way to turn off the share panel only for organization guest users?

I need them to be able to access the folders I have shared with them but not to access the share panel.

In fact, I need them to not be able to even access that panel because searching for users is also a problem.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a workaround will fulfill your requirement to some extent. Go **SharePoint Admin Center(new)**>**Policies**>**Sharing**>**Advanced settings for external Sharing**. Do not choose "**Allow guest users to share items they don't own**" The items they own means the items guest users have full control on.

[image]

The share button will still be there, but the guest users will not be able to use the people picker. In other words they cannot search for users. And they cannot grant access to the file to any other user. The share button only allow the guest user to copy a link to the file. And the link is effective only for users who already has access to the file .

[image]

Comment: I already did it and the Grant Access panel is still there. The guests are not able to actually share the content but they can access that panel and use the people picker, like I showed in my screenshot. Again, the Share panel is correct but the Grant Access is not. You can see that if you click the three dots menu there in your last screenshot and click Manage Access.